# .NET Pooling IAsyncResult Objects

Tags: .net, optimization, memory-management, pooling

Reading through the `SendAsync`, `BeginAsync` method illustrations of `Socket`s, I realized that it was suggested to pool `SocketAsyncEventArgs` instances saying that it is a better than BeginXX, EndXX async approach since each call creates an `IAsyncResult` instance.

I thought it was not that a great practice to pool objects that can be instantiated easily (such as `SocketAsyncEventArgs`). Object allocation is pretty fast and GC is optimized to handle short living objects efficiently. I tried that out implementing a pooling mechanism to see how it performs, actually allocation is faster on simple objects that do nothing but encapsulate some data in ctor. (Well, it was like profiling a DBMS by sending billions of `SELECT 1` statements, that's why I'm here.)

I'm not asking which is better, I believe profiling the actual application would yield the answer but just curious about the benefits of pooling simple short living objects. Better GC performance? Low memory fragmentation? Does it worth to consider it during design?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx)

> The main feature of these enhancements
>   is the avoidance of the repeated
>   allocation and synchronization of
>   objects during high-volume
>   asynchronous socket I/O. The Begin/End
>   design pattern currently implemented
>   by the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class
>   requires a System.IAsyncResult object
>   be allocated for each asynchronous
>   socket operation.
>
> In the new System.Net.Sockets.Socket
>   class enhancements, asynchronous
>   socket operations are described by
>   reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs objects
>   allocated and maintained by the
>   application. High-performance socket
>   applications know best the amount of
>   overlapped socket operations that must
>   be sustained. The application can
>   create as many of the
>   SocketAsyncEventArgs objects that it
>   needs. For example, if a server
>   application needs to have 15 socket
>   accept operations outstanding at all
>   times to support incoming client
>   connection rates, it can allocate 15
>   reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs objects
>   for that purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you read the suggestion? MSDN? Could you link it? Secondly what sort of socket code are you working on? Will it be many clients or some clients with large data. Personally I'd avoid to add extra complexity unless it's explicitly required and in many application pooling just doesn't worth it.

Comment: @dr. evil Added the reference.

It is around 100 clients sending 3-5 small packets / second. I also create "Message" objects for each packet so I was wondering if I should pool them.

Comment: I think you'll be more than fine for 100 clients 3-5 packets per second. I don't think you need to pool Message either (just ensure it's disposed correctly). .NET memory management can handle much more than that easily without a a performance impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IAsyncResult` interface includes an `AsyncWaitHandle` property of type `WaitHandle`. A `WaitHandle` consumes operating system resources.

In fact, `WaitHandle` implements the `IDisposable` interface, so the class implementing  `IAsyncResult` should itself implement `IDisposable`.

This is all to say that hundreds of `IAsyncResult` instances lying around is not a *memory* issue - it's a *resources* issue. The new socket calls get rid of the need for hundreds of `IDisposable` objects lying around.

Answer (score 1):

A cache without an expiration policy is a memory leak.  There's nothing in your question that suggests you have considered a good policy.  If you don't have one then don't use a cache.  If you do then test it to see if you can measure actual improvements.